# How does mnesia:write/1 know the table name?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

In Joe Armstrong's book on Erlang, there's an example of inserting a row into an mnesia database:

```
add_shop_item(Name, Quantity, Cost) ->
    Row = #shop{item=Name, quantity=Quantity, cost=Cost},
    F = fun() ->
        mnesia:write(Row)
    end,
    mnesia:transaction(F).
```

The row gets inserted into a table called `shop`, but how does that happen if Erlang records like `Row` are really just tuples, and mnesia:write/1 doesn't take an argument for the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records are tuples where the first element is an atom that names the record, in this case `shop`. In the mnesia source you can see how it extracts the first element to use as the table name.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/mnesia/src/mnesia.erl#L511-L513

```
write(Val) when is_tuple(Val), tuple_size(Val) > 2 ->
    Tab = element(1, Val),
    write(Tab, Val, write);
```